# How to dynamically assign Policy and Authority at runtime to authenticate the user with Azure AD B2C - IDX10501: Signature validation failed

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I am trying to run the .NET core application where I use multiple sign-in Azure AD B2C policies and custom policies (TrustedFramework). Why multiple? Well one policy is for sign up with local and social accounts. The other custom policy is for linking the social accounts to local accounts ([AccountLinkage example](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack/blob/237fae7530197bf6e13bdc8ef2a9e6d9cf326b05/scenarios/source/aadb2c-ief-account-linkage/Readme.md)).

So i set the policies in controller actions (the code below) and then run the process.

In the event **OnRedirectToIdentityProvider** i replace the policy name with the current and also rename Authority and MetadataAddress. Both endpoints are correct!

But then I get **IDX10501**: Signature validation failed error on event **OnRemoteFailure**. I tripple checked the Authority URI and those are fine.

It looks like I have an issue with **DefaultPolicy**, which is not replaced in **OnRedirectToIdentityProvider** event. If I specify default policy in configuration to AccountLiniking policy then Account policy works and SignIn does not. And vice versa.

Here is my extension class:

```cs
 public static class AzureAdB2CAuthenticationBuilderExtensions
    {
        public static AuthenticationBuilder AddAzureAdB2C(this AuthenticationBuilder builder)
            => builder.AddAzureAdB2C(_ =>
            {
            });

        public static AuthenticationBuilder AddAzureAdB2C(this AuthenticationBuilder builder, Action<AzureAdB2COptions> configureOptions)
        {
            builder.Services.Configure(configureOptions);
            builder.Services.AddSingleton<IConfigureOptions<OpenIdConnectOptions>, OpenIdConnectOptionsSetup>();
            builder.AddOpenIdConnect();
            return builder;
        }

        public class OpenIdConnectOptionsSetup : IConfigureNamedOptions<OpenIdConnectOptions>
        {

            public OpenIdConnectOptionsSetup(IOptions<AzureAdB2COptions> b2cOptions)
            {
                AzureAdB2COptions = b2cOptions.Value;
            }

            public AzureAdB2COptions AzureAdB2COptions { get; set; }

            public void Configure(string name, OpenIdConnectOptions options)
            {
                options.ClientId = AzureAdB2COptions.ClientId;
                options.Authority = AzureAdB2COptions.Authority;
                options.UseTokenLifetime = true;
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters() { NameClaimType = "name"};
                //options.CallbackPath = $"{AzureAdB2COptions.RedirectUri}".Replace("http://localhost:44357","");
                options.SaveTokens = true;

                options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents()
                {
                    OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = OnRedirectToIdentityProvider,
                    OnRemoteFailure = OnRemoteFailure,
                    OnAuthorizationCodeReceived = OnAuthorizationCodeReceived
                };
            }

            public void Configure(OpenIdConnectOptions options)
            {
                Configure(Options.DefaultName, options);
            }

            public Task OnRedirectToIdentityProvider(RedirectContext context)
            {
                var defaultPolicy = AzureAdB2COptions.DefaultPolicy;
                if (context.Properties.Items.TryGetValue(AzureAdB2COptions.PolicyAuthenticationProperty, out var policy) &&
                    !policy.Equals(defaultPolicy))
                {
                    context.ProtocolMessage.Scope = OpenIdConnectScope.OpenIdProfile;
                    context.ProtocolMessage.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.IdToken;
                    context.ProtocolMessage.IssuerAddress = context.ProtocolMessage.IssuerAddress.ToLower().Replace(
                        defaultPolicy.ToLower(), policy.ToLower());
                    context.Options.Authority = context.Options.Authority.ToLower().Replace(
                        defaultPolicy.ToLower(), policy.ToLower());
                    context.Options.MetadataAddress = context.Options.MetadataAddress.ToLower().Replace(
                        defaultPolicy.ToLower(), policy.ToLower());
                   // context.Options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters() { NameClaimType = "name", AuthenticationType = policy};
                   context.Properties.Items.Remove(AzureAdB2COptions.PolicyAuthenticationProperty);
                }
                else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(AzureAdB2COptions.ApiUrl))
                {
                    context.ProtocolMessage.Scope += $" offline_access {AzureAdB2COptions.ApiScopes}";
                    context.ProtocolMessage.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.CodeIdToken;
                }
                return Task.FromResult(0);
            }

            public Task OnRemoteFailure(RemoteFailureContext context)
            {
                context.HandleResponse();
                // Handle the error code that Azure AD B2C throws when trying to reset a password from the login page 
                // because password reset is not supported by a "sign-up or sign-in policy"
                if (context.Failure is OpenIdConnectProtocolException && context.Failure.Message.Contains("AADB2C90118"))
                {
                    // If the user clicked the reset password link, redirect to the reset password route
                    context.Response.Redirect("/Session/ResetPassword");
                }
                else if (context.Failure is OpenIdConnectProtocolException && context.Failure.Message.Contains("access_denied"))
                {
                    context.Response.Redirect("/");
                }
                else
                {
                    context.Response.Redirect("/Home/Error?message=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(context.Failure.Message));
                }
                return Task.FromResult(0);
            }

          ...
        }
    }
```

And here two controller actions that runs different profiles, one for sign in and one for linking:

```cs
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Link()
{
    var redirectUrl = Url.Action(nameof(HomeController.Dashboard), "Home");
    var properties = new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = redirectUrl };
    properties.Items[AzureAdB2COptions.PolicyAuthenticationProperty] = AzureAdB2COptions.AccountLinkingPolicyId;
    return Challenge(properties, OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
}

[HttpGet]
public IActionResult SignIn()
{
    var redirectUrl = Url.Action(nameof(HomeController.Dashboard), "Home");
    var properties = new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = redirectUrl };
    properties.Items[AzureAdB2COptions.PolicyAuthenticationProperty] = AzureAdB2COptions.SignInPolicyId;
    return Challenge(properties, OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
}
```

```cs
    public class AzureAdB2COptions
    {
        public const string PolicyAuthenticationProperty = "Policy";

        public AzureAdB2COptions()
        {
            AzureAdB2CInstance = "https://<name>.b2clogin.com/";
        }

        public string ClientId { get; set; }
        public string AzureAdB2CInstance { get; set; }
       // public string Domain { get; set; }
       public string Tenant { get; set; }
        public string AccountLinkingPolicyId { get; set; }
        public string SignInWithFacebookPolicyId { get; set; }
        public string SignInWithGooglePolicyId { get; set; }
        public string SignInPolicyId { get; set; }
        public string RedirectUri { get; set; }

        public string DefaultPolicy => SignInPolicyId;
        public string Authority => $"{AzureAdB2CInstance}tfp/{Tenant}/{DefaultPolicy}/v2.0";
        public string ClientSecret { get; set; }
        public string ApiUrl { get; set; }
        public string ApiScopes { get; set; }
    }
```

I want to use both policies dynamically in the application to accommodate both scenarios and avoid IDX10501: Signature validation failed error.

IDX10501: Signature validation failed. Unable to match keys: kid: 'G_S3PGi4IAMXXSi1He_GzXYcGoOihMDfUzYjBvGnFq8', token: '{"typ":"JWT","alg":"RS256","kid":"G_S3PGi4IAMXXSi1He_GzXYcGoOihMDfUzYjBvGnFq8"}.{"exp":1563719175,"nbf":1563715575,"ver":"1.0","iss":"https://dev.b2clogin.com/73ffe9fe-..../v2.0/","sub":"7025b366...","aud":"3a9161fc...","acr":"b2c_1a_link_accountlinkage","nonce":"636993127046873524.MTc5N2Q5NDQrMWJlNC00MTBjLWE0NmEtNzE1OWFlOTg1OWZlODQ1NDc2MWUtOWM5Yi00ZWRiLThhNGUtYWFkN2ZkYTQ3ODU1","iat":1563715575,"auth_time":1563715575,"name":"M J","given_name":"M","family_name":"J","extension_UserRole":"Customer","extension_UserType":"Customer","email":"mj@mail.com","idp":"facebook.com"}'.;

Comment: Hi @Miha. Are you using a mix of built-in and custom policies?

Comment: Yes @ChrisPadgett. I was thinking... Is it possible to just redirect to the application withtout sending the claims with the custom profile? Currently the last step in orchestration is the :  <OrchestrationStep Order="8" Type="SendClaims" CpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId="JwtIssuer" />.. Because in case of linking profile we dont need to return the token. We just want to link the accounts?

Comment: Hi @Miha. The built-in and custom policies are associated with different signing keys. So if **DefaultPolicy** is set to a built-in policy, then tokens that are signed for a custom policy won't be failed by the web app (and vice versa). You might consider [the **PolicyConfigurationManager** "pattern"](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-external-identities-woodgrove-demo/blob/2b5110c25d1a626bf9b9ac27ecaaabad8b4bccf4/src/WoodGroveGroceriesWebApplication/Startup.cs#L132) that creates an OpenID Connect configuration for **each** policy (rather than one for *all* policies).

Comment: Ok, I will look into it.